# How to check timezone is automatic or not in system, in electron js

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

How can I detect the timezone of the system is automatic set or not.

Comment: It looks like it depends on the OS and has nothing to do with javascript or any programming language you use. In *Windows* you can check `registry keys` so executing [`regedit`](https://superuser.com/a/1070317/1367305) from within your app will do the job. I assume *Linux* and *OS X* have their own method.